# JFrame text alert as result

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

im working on a little swing application to deal with some multithreading /  synchronization, but that besides the point.
I basically have 3 horses racing and when one finishes a box will pop up and say that *_* horse won.This is what I have right now because i couldn't figure out just a plain window to display the winner.

```
                    if(horsea.getX()>=415){
                        PausableThread.pause();
                        String result=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Horse #1 Wins!");
                        PausableThread.unpause();
                        setReset(true);
                        PausableThread.pause();
                    }
                    else if(horseb.getX()>=415){

                        PausableThread.pause();
                        String result=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Horse #2 Wins!");
                        PausableThread.unpause();
                        setReset(true);
                        PausableThread.pause();

                    }
                    else if(horsec.getX()>=415){

                        PausableThread.pause();
                        String result=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Horse #3 Wins!");
                        PausableThread.unpause();
                        setReset(true);
                        PausableThread.pause();
                    }
```

I know that is a dialog box, and i know there are other methods that are like showMessageDialog or something but idk what the parameters for those are,

thanks for any help!

**EDIT:**

so this is what I want to use but in mine im not sure what "frame" is.

```
                else if(horseb.getX()>=415){

                    PausableThread.pause();
                    String result=JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Horse 2 is the winner", "We Have A Winner!", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                    PausableThread.unpause();
                    setReset(true);
                    PausableThread.pause();

                }
```

That is the kind of message I want to display, but there is an error under where frame is

**EDIT:**

got it by using this!

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getRootPane(),"Horse 2 is the winner", "We Have A Winner!", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

thanks for the help Eels!

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not clear on just what your problem is. Why won't a JOptionPane work for you?

Comment: well JOptionPane.showInputDialog("..."); displays the message but it also displays a text box that i DO NOT want

Comment: What do you mean by "a text box"? What effect are you trying to get? A little more description and/or an image can go a long way towards helping us better understand your problem.

Comment: I want like whats at the top of this page http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JOptionPane.html but what i have now displays my text but there is also a text field

Comment: `im not sure what "frame" is.` - what does the API say it should be? What do the examples for the tutorial use? Did you search the forum/web for other examples that use the method?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use showInputDialog. Use `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(...)` instead if you're going to need to know the user's response, or `showMessageDialog(...)` if not.

Most important, have a look at the [JOptionPanel API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) for a complete description of what JOptionPane options are available and how to use them.

---

**Edit**
You state:

> so this is what I want to use but in mine im not sure what "frame" is.

```
            else if(horseb.getX()>=415){

                PausableThread.pause();
                String result=JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Horse 2 is the winner", "We Have A Winner!", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                PausableThread.unpause();
                setReset(true);
                PausableThread.pause();

            }
```

---

Here we have to know a bit more about your current program. Assuming that your current program shows a main GUI, such as a JFrame or JApplet, and that some event occurs that stimulates one of the JOptionPanes to show. If that is so, then the "frame" variable can refer to *any* component on the main JFrame, or the main JFrame itself. If your program does not have a main JFrame (or other top-level window) showing, then frame can be null.

Also, you will need to get rid of `String result = ...` since a `showMessageDialog(...)` just shows a message and does not return a String. This should generate a compiler error, I would think.

Comment: Yes I know something like that, but im not sure what the arguments mean

Comment: @erp: have you gone to the API (link above and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html))? What parameters *in particular* confuse you?

Comment: +1, @erp, so read the tutorial (you will find a link to the tutorial in the API) and play with the examples in the tutorial.

Comment: @erp: again, the clearer your question, the better our answers can be. If something confuses you, please tell us from the get go.